# adding new line to richtextbox with different color in c#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I created a program that sends a command to the cmd, gets the output from the cmd and show it in a richtextbox with colors.
I wrote this function:

```
           System.Windows.Documents.TextRange rangeOfText =
                new System.Windows.Documents.TextRange(this.Console.Document.ContentEnd,
                    this.Console.Document.ContentEnd)
                { Text = line + "\n" };
            rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color);
```

this.Console is my richtextbox.

the problem is that I get lots of lines from the cmd, so the UI is blocked a lot.
Is there something more effective than this?

Comment: why do you think RichTextBox blocking UI? if RTB size is fixed, how come it blocks your UI, sorry but I am trying to understand your problem.

Comment: for debugging this problem, I created a .txt file with the output of some command and for illustrating this problem I read from this file line by line with sleep of 10 ms between lines. in this case the UI is stuck for few minutes. when I changed it to 1000 ms, I works ok. and if I use the "appendText" method (without changing color) everything is ok. so I understand that my function cant handle lots of lines per sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running too many commands in sort time, then your UI will stuck definitely. You have to create separate thread to read from file and update RichTextBox. DO this. 
1. Crete one thread to read from file. Put interval 100ms.
2. Once you receive data update RichTextBox. Your new thread cannot update the RichTExtBOx, so you have to use `delegate` to update RTB. like "`richTetxbox1.Invoke`"